# How to access file from an external folder in flask server?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am new to flask and am very confused regarding including libraries from external folders into the html template. I know how to include from the `static` folder, but I want to keep my code and the library files in separate folders. So, my directory structure is something like:

```
./main_directory
|
|_./Code
| |_./flask_script.py
| |_./static
|
|_./Libraries
```

I know about the `send_from_directory()` function but I don't understand exactly how to use it. The most common thing I have seen is:

```
@app.route('/cdn/<path:filename>')
def custom_static(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['CUSTOM_STATIC_PATH'], filename)
```

Which is from another StackOverflow answer. But here what is `cdn` in this case? Also, what is the value of `app.confg['CUSTOM_STATIC_PATH']` set to? And what all should be done in the HTML template to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general serving static files with flask is only good for development. Realistically, when going live it is advised to serve static files otherwise, for example having a web server in front of your app and delegating file serving to it, or putting the files in a file store, like AWS S3.

Regarding your `custom_static` route, `cdn` in this case is simply a url prefix (it can be anything), you can then address your static assets from templates like `<img src="/cdn/test.jpg">`. (The `cdn` prefix can give you a hint that these files are later moved to a CDN and aren't served by flask in production).

`app.config['CUSTOM_STATIC_PATH']` should be set to the absolute path to the directory containing your custom static files.

Comment: so will I need to make separate functions for files which are inside subfolders of the library folder?

Comment: ok i got it, it is working. even if the files are in subfolders, it does not affect