# Deploy React app on Heroku - how to jump one folder up

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a Flask backend - React frontend app on Heroku. I've run npm build, now I want to set where to look for the build/index.html file.

The problem is that my app.py file is in a folder "backend", while the build folder is in "frontend".
See my create_app function below:

```
  def create_app(test_config=None):

  app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='../frontend/build', static_url_path='/')
  print(app.static_folder)
  
  setup_db(app)
  CORS(app)

  @app.route('/')
  def index():
    return send_from_directory('../frontend/build', 'index.html')

  return app
```

I tried to jump one level up with '../', './',but nothing helped. I can see in the heroku logs that the static folder becomes:

`/app/backend/../frontend/build`

So I guess it does the same in `send_from_directory`. How can I make it jump one level up and find the frontend folder?

If I run the server locally, it opens the react app fine.

See folder structure here:

```
├── backend
│   ├── app.py
│   └── models.py
├── frontend
│   ├── build
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── public
│   ├── README.md
│   └── src
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.sh
└── venv
    ├── bin
    ├── include
    ├── lib
    ├── lib64 -> lib
    ├── pyvenv.cfg
    └── share
```

Comment: It will be good to have other project structure as one project on backend side to deploy on heroku, after building, you have to serve the index.hml file on flask server with its static files. If the build files in your frontend folder you can not get access them from flask server. Or you can change the build folder from react js config, but I do not know it.

Comment: @Musulmon thanks for your comment. Could you please explain me why it's not possible to access that folder from the server? And where should I put the index.html file then?

Comment: You should read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56971380/how-to-access-file-from-an-external-folder-in-flask-server)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the `static_url_path='/'` use `static_url_path=''`

So the code would be:

```
  def create_app(test_config=None):

  app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='../frontend/build', static_url_path='')
  print(app.static_folder)
  
  setup_db(app)
  CORS(app)

  @app.route('/')
  def index():
    return send_from_directory(static_folder, 'index.html')

  return app
```